# Errors with running a GUI in R

Tags: r, user-interface

I'm attempting to run a code in R that creates a GUI- this was developed by a coworker who is no longer working with us and I was given the task to attempt to get it working again. I don't have a programming background (just familiar with R) and am at a loss with how to address the errors I'm getting to install a package for the GUI. Here is the code:

```
> install("Radamas")
√  checking for file 'Q:\aquatic\AqDataTemp\Vanvj\R-ADAMAS\R\JaneVScripts\Radamas/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'Radamas': (22s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (555ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'Radamas_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz'

Running "C:/Users/VANVES~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-40~1.0/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL \
  "C:\Users\VANVES~1\AppData\Local\Temp\10\Rtmps151dc/Radamas_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz" --install-tests 
* installing to library 'C:/Users/vanvj/Documents/R/R-4.0.0/library'
* installing *source* package 'Radamas' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/RGtk2_2.20.36.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 16529627 bytes (15.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 15.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/RODBC_1.3-17.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 878540 bytes (857 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 857 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/DBI_1.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 656596 bytes (641 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 641 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/sqldf_0.4-11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 78361 bytes (76 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 76 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/FSA_0.8.30.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1223853 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/magrittr_1.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 157428 bytes (153 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 153 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/dplyr_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1294122 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/plotrix_3.7-8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1134284 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ggplot2_3.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4018097 bytes (3.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/gridExtra_2ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'Radamas'
.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1109251 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/lubridate_1.7.9.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1749669 bytes (1.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/devtools_2.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 350872 bytes (342 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 342 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/roxygen2_7.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1372118 bytes (1.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/RColorBrewer_1.1-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 55583 bytes (54 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 54 KB

package 'RGtk2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package 'RGtk2'
Warning in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\00LOCK\RGtk2\gtk\x64\bin\libatk-1.0-0.dll to C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\RGtk2\gtk\x64\bin\libatk-1.0-0.dll: Permission denied
Warning in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\00LOCK\RGtk2\libs\x64\RGtk2.dll to C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\RGtk2\libs\x64\RGtk2.dll: Permission denied
Warning: restored 'RGtk2'
package 'RODBC' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package 'RODBC'
Warning in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
problem copying C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\00LOCK\RODBC\libs\x64\RODBC.dll to C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\RODBC\libs\x64\RODBC.dll: Permission denied
Warning: restored 'RODBC'
package 'DBI' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'sqldf' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'FSA' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'magrittr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'dplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package 'dplyr'
Warning in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\00LOCK\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll to C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll: Permission denied
Warning: restored 'dplyr'
package 'plotrix' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'gridExtra' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'lubridate' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package 'lubridate'
Warning in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\00LOCK\lubridate\libs\x64\lubridate.dll to C:\Users\vanvj\Documents\R\R-4.0.0\library\lubridate\libs\x64\lubridate.dll: Permission denied
Warning: restored 'lubridate'
package 'devtools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'roxygen2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'RColorBrewer' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\vanvj\AppData\Local\Temp\10\Rtmpm2yhXI\downloaded_packages
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/RColorBrewer_1.1-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 55583 bytes (54 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 54 KB
|
package 'RColorBrewer' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\vanvj\AppData\Local\Temp\10\Rtmpm2yhXI\downloaded_packages
Error : Can't find 'C:\Users\VANVES~1\AppData\Local\Temp\10\RtmpSseu9k\R.INSTALL1a085e0947fd\Radamas\ABioQuery'.
Error: unable to load R code in package 'Radamas'
Execution halted
Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  : 
  System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed
Type .Last.error.trace to see where the error occured
> .Last.error.trace

 Stack trace:

 1. devtools:::install("Radamas")
 2. pkgbuild::with_build_tools(required = FALSE, callr::rcmd("INSTALL",  ...
 3. withr::with_path(rtools_path(), code)
 4. base:::force(code)
 5. callr::rcmd("INSTALL", c(install_path, opts), echo = !quiet,  ...
 6. callr:::run_r(options)
 7. base:::with(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run,  ...
 8. base:::with.default(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run,  ...
 9. base:::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 10. base:::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 11. callr:::with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmdargs,  ...
 12. base:::force(code)
 13. base:::do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmdargs,  ...
 14. (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  ...
 15. throw(new_process_error(res, call = sys.call(), echo = echo,  ...

 x System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed
```

Could anyone at least point me in the direction of how to address this error? I admittedly don't even know what the errors are telling me, even after days of google searches. Thank you!

Comment: I'm no expert, but that looks more like a problem for your IT department than for SO.  It looks like a permissions problem.  But welcome all the same.

Comment: Restart R and try it again

Answer (score 0):

Well, the binary package  is reported to be in

C:\Users\ **vanvj** \AppData\Local\Temp\10\Rtmpm2yhXI\downloaded_packages

and then the error message says it was looking in

Can't find 'C:\Users\ **VANVES~1** \AppData\Local\Temp\10\RtmpSseu9k\R.INSTALL1a085e0947fd\Radamas\ABioQuery'.

That suggests that the originator of the package may have hard-coded  his username into something in the build code.  I'm not 100$ sure, but I'd start by looking in your appdata\local\temp\10... directories and see what you find.